# Can I trust apps downloaded from Aptoide?

Tags: security, aptoide

I just downloaded an app from Aptoide that is supposed to allow Screen Off Writing. After installing, it was anything but that.

How much checking does Aptoide do on apps? Can I trust the apps I get from there?

Answer (score 1):

**Anyone** can upload apps to Aptoide, iirc without good, if any, verification.

Aptoide is also known to be a **source of pirated apps**, so if you want to use any app, consider downloading it from Play Store or from the official source.

Many apps are the original ones and considered safe. **If you have concerns, do not use it.**